# How can I run a terminal command from AppleScript?

Tags: terminal, applescript

```
do shell script "screencapture -l$(osascript -e 'tell app 'Transmission' to id of window 1') ~/tempDirectory/test.png"
```

Basically I want to grab a screenshot when a download is completed with Transmission.

This code works in terminal

```
screencapture -l$(osascript -e 'tell app 'Transmission' to id of window 1
```

Comment: What part of your code isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to run an applescript inside a shell script inside an applescript. Just try (untested):

```
tell application "Transmission" to set wid to id of window 1

do shell script "screencapture -l" & wid
```